# Is there a way to fire offline/online events programmatically from the console?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm looking to fire an offline event in Chrome DevTools console to mimic what clicking `DevTools -> Network tab -> (Throttling drop-down) -> "Offline"` would do.

Is there a way to do it programmatically?

Comment: You can run UI.panels.network._offlineCheckbox.inputElement.click() in devtools-on-devtools console ([instruction](/a/41202159))

Comment: @wOxxOm - thank you for your comment. The object `UI.panels.network._offlineCheckbox` doesn't seem defined in the devtools for Chrome 79, but thank you for letting me know about the devtools-on-devtools console, really cool.

Comment: Now it's a listbox so you can change UI.panels.network._throttlingSelect._selectElement.value between 'Online' and 'Offline' and then do UI.panels.network._throttlingSelect._selectElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))